# How to reset pyviz.networkx.draw figure?

Tags: networkx, holoviews

When I plot this graph and make a selection, I would like to undo that the selection as well. There is a button that is labeled "Reset", but that only resets the zoom and pan. What do I have to do to undo the selection though?

```
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, bundle_graph

graph = hv.Graph.from_networkx(nx.karate_club_graph(), nx.spring_layout)

kwargs = dict(width=800, height=800, xaxis=None, yaxis=None, padding=0.1)
opts.defaults(opts.Nodes(**kwargs), opts.Graph(**kwargs))
bundle_graph(graph).opts()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer by trying. Just click somewhere into the figure where no node is.